# For which values ​of  the graph  (hypercube) admits an Eulerian circuit

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have found Qn is an n regulat graph which means if n is even, it admits an Eulerian circuit, is this justification correct for my math homework or do I need to go into more details? Thank you

Comment: Looks fine to me.